# How can i save json api request on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am doing an application similar to an e-commerce application. I bring the products with the json api. When users favorite products, I want to list them on another page. How can I do that?
[image: This is my productions page]

What do i want: when users click fav icon app save this page and show another page

Comment: when the user clicks on favourite, just add the product to a new list, and generate the favourites page from this list?

Comment: can you explain a little more

Comment: for example, you are showing a bike currently, it must have a product id of sorts in the backend right? just store this id in a new list along with the necessary details to be shown in the favourites screen and built the screen using this new list

Comment: thx for ur help i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your favorite list items in local storage, try using hive package to store your data.